# Processing CSV items one by one using awk

Tags: bash, csv, awk

Using the following script to access CSV items.

```
#!/bin/bash
awk -F "|" 'NR > 0 {print $1}' UserAgents.csv
```

When running the script I am getting the correct output, i.e. the entire set of values in the first 'column' of the CSV are printed to the terminal. What I would like to add is to read these items one by one and perform some operation on them like concatenate it with a string, and then output them (to file, pipe, or terminal) one by one.

Comment: your `{print $1}` is getting executed per item, `one by one`. So why not do the action there, try `print "hello there " $1 ` Not putting as an answer, because i feel there might be something else in the problem

Comment: `NR > 0` - if that is to ignore blank lines it should be `NF > 0`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should make it clear what your awk script is doing:

```
awk -F '|' '{
   print NR, NF, $1, "with some trailing text"
}' UserAgents.csv
```

Comment: Thanks it helped me understand the way awk processed entries in a CSV file. Although I ended up using IFS for the final version of my script.

Comment: What does `I ended up using IFS for the final version of my script` mean? There is no IFS bultin variable in awk but there is in shell.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, I meant that I ended up not using awk at all.

Comment: @RaviGupta then you made the wrong choice as this is 100% a job for awk. It's the kind of thing awk was invented for.

Comment: I can share my final script if that will help you help me understand the deficiencies in my solution.

Comment: OK, post a new question along the lines of "how can i improve this script" with the script, sample input, and expected output and tag it with "awk" and whatever other tools you're interested in.